# Testng : Assert using error code, a custom property of custom exception instance

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng

I want my unit test classes to check for the error code (which is a custom property of my exception class) and assert when an exception is thrown from the tested code. Can I do this using testng.

I have the following exception class :

```
public final class CustomException extends Exception {

    public CustomException(String msg,String errorCode,Throwable cause) {
        super(msg,cause);
        this.errorCode = errorCode; 
    }  

    private String errorCode;

    public String getErrorCode() {
        return this.errorCode;
    }
}
```

My Unit Test Class :

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class MyUnitTestClass {


    @Test(priority = 25,
          expectedExceptions = CustomException.class, 
          expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp = "Error while doing something.")
    public void testDoSomething() {
        // code to invoke doSomething();
        // which throws CustomException on some exception.
    }
}
```

Instead of `expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp="Error while doing something."` i want to assert on an error code Eg: like "ERR100909" which will be set in the errorCode property of CustomException class.

Unit Test Framework : Testng
Version : 6.9.4

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the ways in which you can do this is by implementing `IHookable` interface. Here's a sample that shows this in action.

```java
import org.testng.IHookCallBack;
import org.testng.IHookable;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MyUnitTestClass implements IHookable {
    private List<String> errorCodes = Arrays.asList("ERR100909", "ERR100");

    @Override
    public void run(IHookCallBack callBack, ITestResult testResult) {
        callBack.runTestMethod(testResult);
        Throwable t = testResult.getThrowable();
        if (t != null) {
            t = t.getCause();
        }
        boolean shouldFail = (t instanceof CustomException && errorCodes.contains(((CustomException) t).getErrorCode()));
        if (!shouldFail) {
            testResult.setThrowable(null);
            testResult.setStatus(ITestResult.SUCCESS);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() throws CustomException {
        throw new CustomException("test", "ERR100", new Throwable());
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() throws CustomException {
        throw new CustomException("test", "ERR500", new Throwable());
    }
}
```